# Find Selected XML Node's Child

Tags: php, xml

I want to find the stock count by my XML's selected id node with php. Could you help me to update my code? (for example, i want to get id=122's stock count)

```
$myproduct=<<<XML
<product>
<id>121</id>
<name>product 1</name>
<stock>14</stock>
</product>

<product>
<id>122</id>
<name>product 2</name>
<stock>8</stock>
</product>

<product>
<id>123</id>
<name>product 3</name>
<stock>26</stock>
</product>
XML;

$xml=simplexml_load_string($myproduct);
print_r($xml->stock);
```

Comment: Your `$myproduct` does not contain a valid XML document. Please show your actual code or a working representative example.

Comment: Your xml does not have root element. If you really get such fragment to work, add - `$xml=simplexml_load_string('<r>'.$myproduct. '</r>');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml is not valid because it contains multiple root nodes `<product>`

If for example your root is `<products>`, you can use a `foreach` to loop through the `$xml->product`.

The variable `$product` in the loop is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) and you can cast it to a string to get the value.

```
$myproduct=<<<XML
<products>
    <product>
        <id>121</id>
        <name>product 1</name>
        <stock>14</stock>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>122</id>
        <name>product 2</name>
        <stock>8</stock>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>123</id>
        <name>product 3</name>
        <stock>26</stock>
    </product>
</products>
XML;

$xml=simplexml_load_string($myproduct);

foreach($xml->product as $product) {
    if ((string)$product->id === "122") {
        echo $product->stock;
    }
}
```

Or using an [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) expression:

```
$product = $xml->xpath("/products/product[id='122']");
echo $product[0]->stock;
```

That would give you:

> 8

Comment: but.. is there any faster way to do it? it takes 8 seconds :/